# How can I know the absolute path of a running process?

Tags: linux, process, ps

If I have multiple copies of the same application on the disk, and only one is running, as I can see with `ps`, how can I know the **absolute** path to distinguish it from the others?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94357/find-out-current-working-directory-of-a-running-process

Answer (score 183, accepted):

```
% sudo ls -l /proc/PID/exe
```

eg:

```
% ps -auxwe | grep 24466
root     24466  0.0  0.0   1476   280 ?        S     2009   0:00 supervise sshd
% sudo ls -l /proc/24466/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  1 18:05 /proc/24466/exe -> /package/admin/daemontools-0.76/command/supervise
```

Comment: In my system (ubuntu 14.04) you do not have to be superuser to run the `ls` command.

Comment: @jarno `ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/28783/exe: Permission denied` -- it's not about running the `ls` command, it's about accessing the process info of a process not belonging to you. On my box, about 97% of all processes listed in /proc are root processes, and the others are distributed over 11 different users.

Comment: ls: cannot read symbolic link '/proc/87/exe': No such file or directory
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct  9 07:05 /proc/87/exe

Answer (score 35):

Use:

```
pwdx $pid
```

This gives you the current working directory of the pid, not its absolute path.

Usually the `which` command will tell you which is being invoked from the shell:

```
#> which vlc
/usr/bin/vlc
```

Comment: @Kokizzu No, it doesn't because it doesn't answer the question at all. The which command only tells you which binary will be run if you execute the command now. The question was "which binary is already running there". Imagine for example having a dozen jdks on your computer. If you want to know for a running java process which jdk it's been taken from, which doesn't help you with that. It will only tell you which jdk it will be taken from, if you execute it now.

The accepted answer is also the correct one.

Comment: An obvious way this answer is wrong: on my machine I run processes with different JDK versions and some 32bits/64bits. If I want to identify the correct jstack/jmap version for the process the answer above will not work while the accepted answer will.

Comment: @Kokizzu This only answers the question, "What is the current working directory of the process `$pid`?" The edited post still doesn't answer the question. `which` merely tells "If the command is on the path, then what is it?"

Comment: `pwdx` return me the absolute path of the exectuable program of the process depending on pid on redhat x64 6.3.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Answer (score 19):

One way is ps -ef

Comment: didn't work for a specific service, it just provide the relative path

Comment: Helped me identify a process via the command it was started with.

Comment: this one can be executed on iOS

Answer (score 7):

```
ps auxwwwe
```

Source:

https://serverfault.com/questions/62322/getting-full-path-of-executables-in-ps-auxwww-output

Comment: does not show ALL full qualified paths on my linux: "root     24466  0.0  0.0   1476   280 ?        S     2009   0:00 supervise sshd
" for example

Comment: This is more accurate than the other answers... maybe not as useful, but more the right answer. Upvoted.

Comment: Can you add sample output and how to interpret it (for a self-contained answer)? Display of all environment variables makes for a lot of noise. E.g., is it the "_" variable that contains the answer?

Answer (score 7):

`lsof` is an option. You can try something like below:

```
lsof -p PROCESS_ID
```

This will list all the files opened by the process including the executable's actual location. It is then possible to add a few more `awk`, `cut`, `grep` etc. to find out the information that you are looking for.

As an example, I executed the following commands to identify where my 'java' process came from:

```
lsof -p 12345 | awk '{print $NF}' | grep 'java$'
```

Comment: How is this different than already posted answers exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is to use `ps` with options or the `/proc` filesystem info.  That will *usually* work, but is not guaranteed.  In general, there is no definite, guaranteed answer.  For instance, what if the executing file is deleted during execution, so that there is no path to the file?

See [the Unix FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/) for a little more detail, particularly questions 4.3 and 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
readlink /proc/$(pgrep -x -U $(id -ur) APP_NAME)/exe
```

or

```
find /proc/$(pgrep -x -U $(id -ur) APP_NAME)/exe -printf "%l\n"
```

to get the absolute path of APP_NAME running as current user.

Comment: AFAICT this isn't using the PID at all and just errors out

Comment: @electrovir fixed the description.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED due to David Moles' comment, below.

See other answers for the path to the executable.

In case you need it, this will give you the working directory of the process.  You don't need to know the PID:

```
pwdx `pgrep ###process_name###`
```

Comment: The question states “as I can see with `ps`”, so it will probably display the PID

Comment: Ah ok true.  I still find this to be a quicker one liner in many of my use cases.

Comment: This tells you the current working directory of the process, not the path to its executable.

Comment: Good point, they may be different.