# How to find out from which folder a process is running?

Tags: linux, debian, ps

In *nix you can use `ps` to see which process are running. But if an executable has multiple homonimous files in a device, we can't figure where it was invoked from.

This is slightly different from my last question on this subject.
[How can I know the absolute path of a running process?](https://superuser.com/questions/103309/how-can-i-know-the-absolute-path-of-a-running-process)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94357/find-out-current-working-directory-of-a-running-process

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
ls -l /proc/<PID>/cwd
```

Answer (score 7):

Derived rom HUB's answer:

```
readlink /proc/<PID>/cwd
```

or even

```
readlink /proc/$(pgrep <program_name>)/cwd
```

Comment: +1 The output of `readlink` can be parsed better in a script.

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell where a process was invoked *from*, only where it currently *is*. Look at the `cwd` ("current working directory") link instead of `exe`.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94357/find-out-current-working-directory-of-a-running-process ?

> There are 3 methods that I'm aware of:
>
> **pwdx**
>
> $ pwdx PID
>
> **lsof**
>
> $ lsof -p PID | grep cwd
>
> **/proc**
>
> $ readlink -e /proc/PID/cwd

Answer (score 1):

I guess this command should work. It is a little workaround but it works at least on my machine.

> for strlist in $(ps e PID);do if [ ${strlist:0:4} = "PWD=" ]; then echo ${strlist:4};fi;done

Answer (score 0):

When I ran

```
ps auxwwwe | grep executableName > dump
vim dump
```

I was able to look for the part of the path I knew, and then I found out from which subdirectory the command was invoked from